Prompt in GAS: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBody')" on a Google Sheets
I'm new at GAS and I was following a tutorial on Youtube for knowing how it works on the diferent plataforms on Google Workspace. But, when I executed my code in a Google Sheets it prompted me this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBody')

function InsertarDatos() {
  var DocActual = DriveApp.getFileById("1kM-zglMjbckKnacmV5K21j1r3CjDmn70yrzsCcKrNdw");
  var fila = 2;
  var nombreCelda = "A" + fila;
  var hojaActual = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var celdaActual = hojaActual.getRange(nombreCelda);

  while (!celdaActual.isBlank()) {
    var DocNuevo = DocActual.makeCopy("Nombre: " + hojaActual.getRange("A" + fila).getValue());
    var documento = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

    var fecha = new Date();
    var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    var dia = fecha.getDate();
    var ano = fecha.getFullYear();
    var fechaT = "Certificado emitido el día " + dia + "del mes " + mes + " de " + ano + ".";
    
    documento.getBody().replaceText("<<nombre>>", hojaActual.getRange("A" + fila).getValue());
    documento.getBody().replaceText("<<dni>>", hojaActual.getRange("B" + fila).getValue());
    documento.getBody().replaceText("<<curso>>", hojaActual.getRange("C" + fila).getValue());
    documento.getBody().replaceText("<<empresa>>", hojaActual.getRange("D" + fila).getValue());
    documento.getBody().replaceText("<<calific>>", hojaActual.getRange("E" + fila).getValue());
    documento.getBody().replaceText("<<fecha>>", fechaT);

    fila++;
    nombreCelda = "A" + fila;
    celdaActual = hojaActual.getRange(nombreCelda);
  }
}

I expected that it created several documents replacing the different items that I would put in a database in a Google Sheets.The expected document

You are using spreadSheet.getActive() and documentApp.getActive() which one is the active document.  There can be only one.  Where's the code being contained

DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() returns null because the Google Apps Script project is contained by a spreadsheet.
You might replace this with DocumentApp.openById(document_id) or DocumentApp.openByUrl(document_url). You should replace document_id / document_url with a string holding the document id / URL, respectively, or a variable to which this string was assigned.
Related

Reference : TypeError: Cannot read property [property name here] from undefined


Thank you so much Wicket, I've tried it, and it works perfectly. Now I got another problem, and it's that when I try to generate the documents, the code only gets the data from the first row... And I thought that with that code, it would have got the other data from the next rows.

@AsierPárraga I am glad that these answers help you. Please take a look to What should I do when someone answers my question. Regarding the "other problem", follow-up questions like that should be asked by posting a new question, not in comments. Your new question should include sample data.

Thanks, @Wicket, I'll keep that in mind!!
